# JAX-RS y JSR 311

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Bueno mi duda es la siguiente: ¿que diferencia hay entre `JAX-RS` y `JSR 311`? Ya que tengo entendido que `JAX-RS` es una implementación (o sea, una API) de `JSR 311` y `JSR 311` es la especificación. Pero me he encontrado con APIs (como `Jersey`) que dicen que son implementaciones de `JAX-RS`, y que `JAX-RS` es la especificación. Entonces ahí esta mi duda, ¿qué es cada cosa? Y en caso de que `JAX-RS` no sea una especificación, ¿`Jersey` toma la API de `JAX-RS` y la extiende?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿que diferencia hay entre JAX-RS y JSR 311?

Un JSR es un documento que contiene la especificación técnica de una tecnología. Define los estándares que deben cumplirse. Se puede interpretar como la definición del "qué", no del "cómo".

Para el caso de [JSR 311](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/spec/spec.html), esta es una especificación de consumo de servicios REST desde Java, comúnmente conocido como JAX-RS. Aquí se explican los detalles de las interfaces provistas en JAX-RS. No se define la implementación. Cabe resaltar que el JSR 311 apunta a JAX-RS versión 1.x. Para la versión 2.x existe el [JSR 339](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=339).

Se puede decir que JAX-RS 1.x es sinónimo de JSR 311, mientras que JAX-RS 2.x es sinónimo de JSR 339.

> tengo entendido que JAX-RS es una implementación ...

No es así. JAX-RS es la especificación, no es ninguna implementación. Eso sí, provee la definición de las interfaces necesarias que debe tener la implementación. Ejemplos de implementación del estándar son [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) y [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/).

> ¿Jersey toma la API de JAX-RS y la extiende?

No, Jersey (y otras implementaciones) toman las definiciones de JAX-RS como parte de la implementación que provee, tal como se explica en párrafos anteriores.

Comment: Entonces, para ver si entendí bien, JAX-RS es un conjunto de interfaces sin implementar que las APIs como Jersey o RESTEasy (de JBoss) toman e implementan, no? Y JSR 311-339 son los papeles que dicen que interfaces contiene JAX-RS. ¿Entendí bien la explicación?

Comment: La primera parte es correcta. La segunda parte, solo te diría que los JSRs son más que "papeles", por lo demás sí, es correcto.

Comment: ¿A que haces referencia cuando decís que son más que papeles @Luiggi?

Comment: @AugustoHerbel porque es el resultado del esfuerzo de la comunidad no solo bajo la documentación para implementar, a veces puede incluir un conjunto de pruebas (unitarias o de integración) para evaluar que tu implementación cumple con los requisitos mínimos para poder denominarse una implementación del estándar.

Comment: Aaah pensé que era únicamente el conjunto de papeles que definen las reglas que debe cumplir la implementación para ser estándar. Muchas gracias @Luiggi Mendoza.